# Close Activity on back press not popBackStack()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have added a fragment with addToBackStack(null) like:

```
 fragment = new MyBrowser();
            manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(0, 0, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

and if i press back button the regular method popBackStack() happens and the fragment is removed from the activity but i need to close the app directly without popBackStack();

I tried placing

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

inside onBackPressed();

but what happens is first fragment is removed then the app closes. I want to directly close the app.

Comment: just add `finish()` into `onBackPressed`

Comment: let me check...

Comment: Thanks @Vladyslav Matviienko but is it ok to use finish();

Comment: what do you want to add fragment to popBackStack when closing app ?

Comment: No actually while replacing the fragment i want to add it to backstack but on back press i want to close the app directly.

Comment: are you calling super.onBackPressed in your onBackPressed method ?

Comment: Yes i am calling it on onBackPressed()

Comment: BTW, why do you want fragment to be added top backstack?

Comment: For popenter and popexit animation

Comment: I don;t think it relates to backstack

Comment: When we don't add fragments to backstack then the popEnter and popExit animation will no get called if we invoke popBackStack();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove it `.addToBackStack(null)`.

Another option(workaround) would be overwriting `onBackPressed` and calling `activity.finish()`

Comment: Actually i want fragment added to backstack

Answer (score 1):

For this type of situation You can use below Code. Here in this Code i count backstack entry and when i found backstack entry 1 at that time i just exit app.

```
  if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            //ExitApp();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            for (int i = 1; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            }
        }
```